# Sorting records by field backwards (not top to bottom)

Tags: text-processing

I have a little script which does a bunch of mounting in preparation for backing up, or which just shows you all currently mounted partitions. I've made it so that it will sort the output on several criteria, the partial output below sorts by partition label:

```
Label              Filesystem       Size  

[a2--0-boot]       /dev/sda2        179M  
[a8--2-home]       /dev/sda8        2.0G  
[a9--1-var]        /dev/sda9        996M  
[b2--1-boot]       /dev/sdb2       1008M  
[b11-2-home]       /dev/sdb11       2.0G  
[b14-2-var]        /dev/sdb14       2.0G
```

... However, it would be useful to be able to sort the partition labels backwards, note I don't mean 'upside down', I mean like this:

```
[a8--2-home]       /dev/sda8        2.0G  
[b11-2-home]       /dev/sdb11       2.0G  
[a9--1-var]        /dev/sda9        996M  
[b14-2-var]        /dev/sdb14       2.0G  
[a2--0-boot]       /dev/sda2        179M  
[b2--1-boot]       /dev/sdb2       1008M
```

... The reason being, simply that the labels of source partitions and target partitions have the same 'endings', but they start differently due to being on  different disks and having different partition numbers, so a backwards sort would list sources and targets together, which would be convinient.

(FWIW, 'a8--2-home' means partition '/dev/sda8', about 2GB in size, and mounted as '/home'.)

I've tried everything I can think of, and spent hours looking for answers but no luck so far. Can this be done? 'Sort'  seems unable to pull it off. In particular the '-r' switch gives an 'upside down' listing, but not the 'backwards' sort I'm looking for.

Comment: Please do not re-edit the `/perl` tag back in as this was not as explicit topic of the original post.  I love perl and that's what I would use for stuff like this, but suggestions should be suggestions, and not modifications to the question.

Comment: By George, I think I've got it:  

    "  cat inputfile | rev | sort -k7 |rev "  

Sick and twisted, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could sort on the part of the first field that starts at offset 8:

```
$ sort -k1.8 < file
[a2--0-boot]       /dev/sda2        179M
[b2--1-boot]       /dev/sdb2       1008M
[a8--2-home]       /dev/sda8        2.0G
[b11-2-home]       /dev/sdb11       2.0G
[a9--1-var]        /dev/sda9        996M
[b14-2-var]        /dev/sdb14       2.0G
```

If your system has a `rev` command, you can do:

```
$ rev < file | sort -k3 | rev
[b11-2-home]       /dev/sdb11       2.0G
[a8--2-home]       /dev/sda8        2.0G
[a9--1-var]        /dev/sda9        996M
[b14-2-var]        /dev/sdb14       2.0G
[a2--0-boot]       /dev/sda2        179M
[b2--1-boot]       /dev/sdb2       1008M
```

To only reverse the first field:

```
rev1() {
  sed -e 's/^/\
/;:1' -e 's/\(.*\n\)\([^[:blank:]]\)/\2\1/;t1' -e 's/\n//'
}
rev1 < file | sort | rev1
```

Comment: But I don't want to reverse the field, only to *sort* it in reverse order.

Comment: @rayandrews, you'll notice the `rev` and `rev1` are done on both side of the `sort`. It's just reversed for `sort` and  reversed again to get back to the original.

Comment: Quite so, missed that. I wish the display box was wider.

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
# !/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    push @r, [ $_, split /\s+/, $_ ];
}

map { print $_->[0] }
sort { (reverse $a->[1]) cmp (reverse $b->[1]) }  
@r;
```

Data is being read from stdin in the while loop and prepared for the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).
 The last 3 lines are one instruction.

Comment: Yikes! perl, the thing I've been trying to avoid ;-)

Comment: @rayandrews: good explained in [Effective Perl](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Perl-Programming-Writing-Programs/dp/0201419750/ref=sr_1_2/189-4869971-4594604?ie=UTF8&qid=1390217903&sr=8-2&keywords=effective+perl), used for $0.01

Comment: Tch.  My bad. +1 for referring to the Schwartzian Transform, although in fact it's unnecessary (and hence) inefficient here because it requires an O(N) pre-processing of the data (your while loop).  It would be better to skip that and sort based on a substring or capture group.

Comment: What I meant was, it's better to avoid the Schwartzian transform if you don't need it.  Of course you do need the `while` loop here anyway to read in, so I'm being theoretical, but pretend the array is pre-existing: `sort { (substr $a, 7) cmp (substr $b, 7) }`.

Comment: The most efficient would be a insert sort. Iduno if sort uses it. However all languages have some kind of limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Use rev to revert the lines. Use awk to print the third column first. Use sort to sort, then use cut to remove the first column again, and use rev to revert the lines again:

```
tweedleburg:~ # rev test | awk '{printf $3;printf " ";print}'| sort|cut -d " " -f 2-|rev
[a8--2-home]       /dev/sda8        2.0G  
[b11-2-home]       /dev/sdb11       2.0G  
[a9--1-var]        /dev/sda9        996M  
[b14-2-var]        /dev/sdb14       2.0G  
[a2--0-boot]       /dev/sda2        179M  
[b2--1-boot]       /dev/sdb2       1008M
```

http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Shell_scripting_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, but I think mine is best:

```
cat inputfile | rev | sort -k7 |rev
```

Sick and twisted, but it works just fine. Tho I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
tac inputfile | sort -k7 | rev
```